# Access Java API`s in Flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I am asking the question because I am not able to understand one concept, how to call Java method that is defined in third-party JAR that takes POJO and returns a POJO in Flutter/Dart? Can Java object be converted/marshaled to Dart object equivalent?

Basically, the app will have the UI, which is built in Flutter and it requires to access business logic, which is defined in the already existing JAR. Is it possible to achieve it?

Comment: I think you are referring to Platform Channels. Looak at this:  https://medium.com/@atul.sharma_94062/creating-a-bridge-in-flutter-between-dart-and-native-code-in-java-or-objectivec-5f80fd0cd713

Comment: @RobertoManfreda example in there is just a simple method that does not take any arguments. Is it possible to pass complex objects? And should they be in Dart or Java or JSON string ?

Comment: Read about "Platform channel data types support and codecs" in flutter documentation https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels